# How to fix "Error: Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module '@angular/localize/src/tools/src/extract/extraction'" in Angular?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, internationalization

I tried to test the i18n features described in https://angular.io/guide/i18n#localizing-your-app but I cannot run the i18n extractor because it cannot be found.

I am using:

- node v14.17.6
- npm v6.14.15
- ng v12.2.5

I wanted to add an example project here, but due to corporate network restrictions I am unable to push it to GitHub... So, what I did was:

1. run `ng new ng-i18n-test`
2. run `cd ng-i18n-test`
3. run `ng add @angular/localize`
4. replace the contents of app.component.html with `<p i18n>Hello World</p>`
5. run `ng extract-i18n`

That leads to the following error:

```
./src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module '@angular/localize/src/tools/src/extract/extraction'
Require stack:
- C:\workspace\ng-i18n-test\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\extract-i18n\ivy-extract-loader.js
- C:\workspace\ng-i18n-test\node_modules\webpack\lib\ProgressPlugin.js
- C:\workspace\ng-i18n-test\node_modules\webpack\lib\index.js
- C:\workspace\ng-i18n-test\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\webpack\index.js
- C:\workspace\ng-i18n-test\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\index.js
- C:\workspace\ng-i18n-test\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\extract-i18n\index.js
- C:\workspace\ng-i18n-test\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
- C:\workspace\ng-i18n-test\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\index.js
- C:\workspace\ng-i18n-test\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js
- C:\workspace\ng-i18n-test\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\extract-i18n-impl.js
- C:\workspace\ng-i18n-test\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js
- C:\workspace\ng-i18n-test\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js
- C:\workspace\ng-i18n-test\node_modules\@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js
- C:\workspace\ng-i18n-test\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js
- C:\workspace\ng-i18n-test\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js
- C:\workspace\ng-i18n-test\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\init.js
- C:\workspace\ng-i18n-test\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:889:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\workspace\ng-i18n-test\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\extract-i18n\ivy-extract-loader.js:29:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)

./src/polyfills.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/extract-i18n/ivy-extract-loader.js):
Error: Cannot find module '@angular/localize/src/tools/src/extract/extraction'
Require stack:
- C:\workspace\ng-i18n-test\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\extract-i18n\ivy-extract-loader.js
- C:\workspace\ng-i18n-test\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js
- C:\workspace\ng-i18n-test\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js
- C:\workspace\ng-i18n-test\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js
- C:\workspace\ng-i18n-test\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js
- C:\workspace\ng-i18n-test\node_modules\webpack\lib\ProgressPlugin.js
- C:\workspace\ng-i18n-test\node_modules\webpack\lib\index.js
- C:\workspace\ng-i18n-test\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\webpack\index.js
- C:\workspace\ng-i18n-test\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\index.js
- C:\workspace\ng-i18n-test\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\extract-i18n\index.js
- C:\workspace\ng-i18n-test\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
- C:\workspace\ng-i18n-test\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\index.js
- C:\workspace\ng-i18n-test\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js
- C:\workspace\ng-i18n-test\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\extract-i18n-impl.js
- C:\workspace\ng-i18n-test\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js
- C:\workspace\ng-i18n-test\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js
- C:\workspace\ng-i18n-test\node_modules\@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js
- C:\workspace\ng-i18n-test\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js
- C:\workspace\ng-i18n-test\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js
- C:\workspace\ng-i18n-test\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\init.js
- C:\workspace\ng-i18n-test\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:889:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\workspace\ng-i18n-test\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\extract-i18n\ivy-extract-loader.js:29:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
```

Frankly, I am not sure what went wrong. It is was is written in the i18n guide. What went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works on a different machine. I guess there has to be an issue with my machine... Great. I'll check my setup.

**Edit** yep, it was a bad setup. Not sure what the issue was. I created a new one using the steps above and it works now.